# Will my quick parts keep their values when the document is moved?

Tags: document-library, quick-parts

I have a document library with some word documents that are using quick parts to grab information from columns (document number and title) and include them within the document.

When I move these documents to another library, will the quick parts keep their current values? What will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick parts will retain their values. If the other document library has the same content type with the same columns, the document will slot in nicely. If you want to ensure that this happens, you may want to ensure that the content types of the libraries match.